# PDO Set Query Table variable

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, lumen

Is it possible to query using PDO and assigning the table as a variable?

ex:

```
        $db = new PDO($this->driver . ":server={$this->host};Database={$this->database_name};", $this->username, $this->password);

        $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $db->setAttribute( PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 200 );

        $query = 'SELECT top 10 * FROM ' . $this->table . ' ' . $query;
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I need to be able to pass the Table name as an argument. I have tried many things, but nothing seems to work. I have also tried `sqlsrv_query`

I'm using lumen as my framework. not sure if there is anything I can use to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is your query statement.  You have $query added to the end of your $query.

Try:

```
$query = 'SELECT top 10 * FROM ' . $this->table;
```

On a second note.  It is very important to only do this if you trust the content of `$this->table`.  Meaning that it is not user generated.  PDO does not allow for parameterized table names.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method: (check `$stmt` for changes)

```
    $db = new PDO($this->driver . ":server={$this->host};Database={$this->database_name};", $this->username, $this->password);

    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 200 );

    $query = 'SELECT top 10 * FROM :table';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(
        array(
           ':table' => $this->table
       );
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I don't think PDO lets you do that.

Comment: You can't use a placeholder for table or column names, only where an expression is allowed.

Comment: Your method works fine for parameters, but it can not be used for column names or table names.